# How to ignore all files of an extension in a certain folder in Sourcetree?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I need to ignore .css in a folder that contains a .php as well

Is it possible to ignore only the .css in that folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes why not? You can define a folder with wildcards.

```
/yourfolder/*.css
```

for example.

http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a '!' symbol to exclude the files. For example if you want to exclude all the css files from your folder say 'My_Folder':

src:['!MyFolder/*.css']

can be used.

Comment: Like that in Sourcetree? The syntax is different, I guess.

Comment: My mistake. Use a gitignore file instead. Inside the file you should mention all the files you want to ignore. As mentioned by @stony below. A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected